# overhead of pthread_rwlock_rdlock when no write locks held

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

If there are no write locks held on a pthread_rwlock_t, is there a lot of overhead to calling pthread_rwlock_rdlock / pthread_rwlock_unlock?

Here is the situation I am thinking of.  If there are other heuristics that might be useful, it would be great to hear of them.

You have a simple program which transforms a list of input data into output results by calling a function on each item of input. Some of the inputs are the same, or at least, similar enough that your function can memoize computations.  Let's say you choose to memoize this function using a hash.

As the program progresses, the hash grows and hit rate approaches 100%.

Below is a possible solution using a pthread_rwlock_t.  One shortcoming of this is that, even as the program approaches 100% hit rate, the function is still calling rdlock / unlock.

At some point, one wonders whether it is best to set a flag called 'hash_frozen' and at that point regard it as constant shared data, and not add any more keys at that point.  This seems like a clunky solution however.

```
struct hash h;
pthread_rwlock_t rwl = ...;

struct val fcn(struct inp i)
{
    struct hashkey k;
    struct hashval v;
    pthread_rwlock_rdlock(rwl);
    if ((k = hash_find(h, i)) != hash_end(h))
    {
        struct retval v = hash_val(k);
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(rwl);
        return v;
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(rwl);
        /* i'm aware that another thread could insert the value at
           this moment, duplicating work, but let's ignore that minor
           inefficiency. */
        pthread_rwlock_wrlock(rwl);
        struct retval v = compute_value(i);
        k = hash_put(h, i);
        hash_val(k) = v; /* let's say this is a macro, as in khash.h */
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(rwl);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This obviously depends on the specific implementation.

With the [current glibc (NPTL) implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.c;h=0edca654a3181d8e466ec8f054c11cb41a2874a4;hb=HEAD#l97), even in the rdlock fast path each reader must take and release a low-level lock protecting the rwlock data structure itself.  If there's not a lot of contention on this low-level lock - ie. your threads are doing significant work either inside or outside read-locked section - then this low-level lock will execute entirely in the fastpath too and the overhead will only be that imposed by the hardware keeping the memory containing the low-level lock and the `__nr_readers` counter synchronised between CPUs.

If there *is* sufficient contention on this low-level lock - because you have so many read-locker executing so quickly that a significant fraction of them end up executing `pthead_rwlock_rdlock()` or `pthread_rwlock_unlock()` at the same time - some of them will end up sleeping on that lock and having to be woken by an unlocker, which will add significant overhead.

So really, it comes down to: are you talking 4 cores, or 4 thousand cores? Ultimately the best way to find out will be to implement and profile it.

If rwlock contention does turn out to be significant, then for the case of a non-resizing hash table you can lock in a more granular manner by having multiple rwlocks, each covering a disjoint subset of the hash table entries.  You calculate the hash without a lock held (hence the 'non-resizing' criteria), and use the hash to look up which rwlock to lock before you check the hash entry itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for another great answer @caf.  Currently I'm using 32 cores, and in have in fact implemented this with read locks.  My application indeed spends most of the time in lock contention, unfortunately.  I like your idea to calculate hash value in advance, only locking the necessary portion of the hash.  Unfortunately, I don't think that technique will work with khash.h's hash, since it uses "quadratic probing", which means a single flat array of buckets, (not a linked list under each hash value).  No way to sequester portions of the table.